# Cookie policy and legal notices

Tags: cookies

I would like to draw up the cookie policy and legal notice that will be associated with my website hosted by heroku. As a result, I need to identify the servers on which my site is hosted but I can't get the associated information ... Do you know where I can get them?

Thanks in advance

I don't know where to search the information